# I need to run XCode 4.3 project twice in order to launch the cocos2d application

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

it drives me crazy, that my cocos2d project runs every second time on the device.

Every other time it says "Finished running " without launching the application.

My os version is 10.7.3 and I run xCode 4.3.

Other projects seems to work fine.

Any ideas?

BR,
Marcin

Comment: I solved it :)

I had 2 Info.plist files under Resources folder. One of them was also under Copy bundle Resources tap in Build Phases section of the target.

I don't know how this happen, however I deleted one of the plist file, then remove it from the Copy Bundle Resources tab and now the project runs every time.

Comment: How did you find it was that file? I am having the same problem, but it isn't the Info.plist file. It could be another file. Was there a method you used to find the faulty file?

Comment: @Omega - Unfortunately I found it by accident - while I was inspecting the whole project file by file. XCode does not report, that something was wrong. I simply saw 2 files with the same name in Project Navigator pane.

Answer (score 1):

There were two `Info.plist` files under `Resources` folder. One of them was also under `Copy bundle Resources` tab in `Build Phases` section of the target.

I don't know how this happen, however I deleted one of the `plist` files, then removed it from the `Copy Bundle Resources` tab and now the project runs every time.

I found the second file while I was inspecting the whole project file by file. XCode does not report, that something goes wrong. I simply saw two files with the same name in `Project Navigator` pane.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way to automatically do this.

Click the project icon, go to target, go to Build Phases tab, and at the bottom you should find the Validate Settings button. Click it. A window will show with an option to clean the "multiple references" of a resource. Use that, and XCode will do the rest.